# Mongo Authentication when mongod started as a service

Tags: mongodb, systemctl

System specs:

- OS: Debian 10
- Mongo Shell: v4.4.4
- Mongod: v4.4.4

I successfully created a user administrator for MongoDB with the privileges below (output from `show users` in Mongo Shell).

```
{
    "_id" : "admin.admin",
    "userId" : UUID("eca59ae2-66bd-42a7-b3d8-b946915922b7"),
    "user" : "admin",
    "db" : "admin",
    "roles" : [
        {
            "role" : "root",
            "db" : "admin"
        },
        {
            "role" : "userAdminAnyDatabase",
            "db" : "admin"
        }
    ],
    "mechanisms" : [
        "SCRAM-SHA-1",
        "SCRAM-SHA-256"
    ]
}
```

I also made the necessary updates to /etc/mongod.conf to enable authentication:

```
security:
  authorization: enable
```

And everything works well when I launch mongod from shell with `sudo mongod --auth`. I can connect with credentials with the command:

```
mongo mongodb://localhost:27017/admin?authSource=admin --username 'admin' --password <mypassword>
```

I then shutdown mongod and try to start it as a service with: `sudo systemctl start mongod`, at which point authentication no longer works. The same mongo connect command shown above now gives the output:

```
MongoDB shell version v4.4.4
connecting to: mongodb://localhost:27017/admin?authSource=admin&compressors=disabled&gssapiServiceName=mongodb
Error: Authentication failed. :
connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:374:17
@(connect):2:6
exception: connect failed
exiting with code 1
```

Any ideas what would cause this?